# Changing of the image when song changes

Tags: android

I am creating android application, in that i have database with fields images,audiofiles,text
with 108 records in that.

here i need to play all the 108 audio files continuously and i need to change the images associated with the audio files when songs changed.

i can play all the audio files continuously but i am stoping at to change the images.
please help me how to do that or provide some code  snippets for that..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a kind of voice recognition or NLP algorithms to solve the propblem

Comment: thank you for your reply, Can you please provide me the link of the nlp alg.